# Check if a String contains X letters and Y numbers in php

Tags: php

I'm developing an application where the user will insert an vehicle ID.

I need to check if the string contain 3 Letters and 4 numbers like "ABC1234"

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid having minus point of the question. Answer to Your question is to use regular expression, its good add example data that You have and desired results : )

Comment: To check Your regex You can use https://regexr.com/. This is php regexp function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easy done by this regullar expression [regex](https://regexr.com/5bs10). I take array of vechicles IDs and iterate and check if each of this ID is correct with given pattern.

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$vehicles = [
'AAA1234',
'BBB2345',
'CCC5432',
'notValid33333',
'notValid212312'
];

$matches=[];

foreach($vehicles as $v){
   preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][\d][\d][\d]/', $v, $matches[]);
}

print_r($matches);
```

[Code Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7719d9148a7973d41c789733fb76eb5b9a897674)